# How to write list which contains comma in csv file using python?

Tags: python, list, csv

List contains below data,

> ['Obama', 'John Barta', 'IN, 33, 33', '444', '']

I am trying to write this data into a csv file using below code,

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(colValues)
```

But getting below output in csv file,

> "Obama","John Barta",'"IN, 33, 33"',"444",""

I don't want single quote between '"IN, 33, 33"'.

**Desired output:**

> "Obama","John Barta","IN, 33, 33","444",""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample output, it looks like you want to quote all fields. So the straightforward way to do it would be with:

```
writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',',
               quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

I also changed `quotechar` to be a double quote, since that's in your sample output also.

Answer (score 3):

If you eliminate the `quotechar` argument from the `csv.writer` call, it should give you the desired behavior. For example, your function call would become

```
writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

The `quotechar` argument is what is placed when the `delimiter` or some other special character is present.

Comment: I had tried that one too. but it gives an error,
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simple, but with defaults write, read returns the original list:

```
import csv

col_values = ['Obama', 'John Barta', 'IN, 33, 33', '444', '']

with open('data.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerow(col_values)

#=> Obama,John Barta,"IN, 33, 33",444,

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    p_list = list(reader)
print(p_list)
#=> [['Obama', 'John Barta', 'IN, 33, 33', '444', '']]
```